# How to scale a Node.js service that uses other services?

Tags: node.js, rest, heroku

I have built a JSON service that uses two other services, each of which has some latency, and as a result of this dependency each request can take up to 800 ms to finish.

One of the major reasons I went with Node.js was for the evented IO. I want the new requests to be handled smoothly, and not hang, as the slow requests are being finished.

How can I test the service and get some reliable metrics on how my service will perform on Heorku -- which is hard to figure out because I don't want to hit my query limits on the other services I am dependent on. How many simultaneous requests will my service accept? What can I do to maximize this number?

In addition, I'd like to get some feedback on whether Node.js going to provide me with better performance in this scenario, over, say, Rails?

(Oh, and...is Heroku a good choice to deploy a service? Sorry..I'm new to Node. )

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not use memory session but use DB session, Memcached or Redis session for sharing states.

Second, you should separate delayed processes to `worker process` and use **worker queue** to add and fetch those delayed jobs. You can use Redis as queue which is [kue](http://learnboost.github.com/kue/) or using other messaging queues are good alternatives.

Third, be sure to be remained non-blocking on your node codes. `process.nextTick` is the key.

---

You can test many simultaneous requests with [Blitz](https://addons.heroku.com/blitz) which is one of add-ons on **Heroku**.